# Conditionally test for a category level

Tags: categories

I want to display different code blocks if a category level is 1 or 2 or 3 – on a category page, but finding this hard to do, 
if I'm on an entry page I can use:

```
{% if entry.level == 1 %}
```

how can I use the equivalent but for a category on a category page?
Thanks

Comment: Did you tried this: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/category-queries.html#parameters ?

Comment: Thank you, I need to update this post as my code must have been wrong as – the simple line:   
```{% if category.level < 2 %}``` does work!